# How can I check if Java 3D is installed from my java application?

Tags: java, java-3d

How can I check if Java 3D is instaled on the client? I can use that to display a message about missing requirements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In my case the J3D jar file was available but not the platform binaries.

```
try
{
   GraphicsConfigTemplate3D gconfigTemplate = new GraphicsConfigTemplate3D();
   GraphicsConfiguration config = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getBestConfiguration(gconfigTemplate);
}
catch (Error e) // You shouldn't normally catch java.lang.Error... this is an exception
{
   System.out.println("Java3D binaries not installed");
}
```

Comment: I consider this one more complete than the previous. Sounds like having the jars is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could try loading a class from the Java 3D API and put your logic in the catch statement. ie

```
try {
    Class.forName("javax.media.j3d.J3DBuffer")
}
catch(final ClassNotFoundException e) {
//Your logic here
}
```

I know, I know, exceptions should not be expected.